# Pivot table creation from excel 2016 to 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code that based on a set of data creates a Pivot table in a new sheet. The problem is that sometimes it skips the creation of the pivot table.
That skipping only ocurrs in excell 2013, on excel 2016 it always creates the pivot tables.

I checked regarding size but it creates bigger files 100.000 items per example while the one skiping is 80.000

```
'Define Data Range
lastrow = DSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:=NameTable)


'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:=NameTable)
```

It should create a pivot table in the new sheet

Comment: `Version` is optional in `PivotCaches.Create`. Have you tried excluding that argument?

Comment: Yes, my original code was without version. Then i added to check but it still happens the same...